# Form in Javascript return me an "undefined" alert

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm a begginner in Javascript and I made a little form as a test. But I can't get the value of the input tags. I always get the alert as "undefined".

```
var id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6, id7, notabx, op1, op2, mu1, mu2;
var doc = document;

var id1 = doc.getElementById("1").value;
var id2 = doc.getElementById("2").value;
var id3 = doc.getElementById("3").value;
var id4 = doc.getElementById("4").value;
var id5 = doc.getElementById("5").value;
var id6 = doc.getElementById("6").value;
var id7 = doc.getElementById("7").value;
var op1 = doc.getElementById("op").value;
var op2 = doc.getElementById("op2").value;
var bx = doc.getElementById("bx").value;

function init() {
    var FG = ( id1 + id2 + id3 + id4 + id5 ) / 5 ;
    var FE = ( id6 * op1 ) + ( id7 * op2 );
    var result =  (bx * (60/100)) + (FG * (40/100)) + FE;
}

function result() {
    alert(result);
}

window.onload = init();
</head>
<body>

<form>
<label for="bx">1st Cours:</label><input type="text" id="bx" value=""><p>
<br>
<p>FASE GENERAL</p>
    <label for="1">Subject #1 </label><input type="text" id="1" maxlength="5" value="">
    <label for="2">Subject #2 </label><input type="text" id="2" maxlength="5" value="">
    <label for="3">Subject #3 </label><input type="text" id="3" maxlength="5" value="">
    <label for="4">Subject #4 </label><input type="text" id="4" maxlength="5" value="">
    <label for="5">Subject #5 </label><input type="text" id="5" maxlength="5"  value="">

<p>FASE ESPECÍFICA</p>
    <label for="6">Subject #6 </label><input type="text" id="6" maxlength="5" value=""><p>
    <select name="" id="op">
        <option value="0.1">0.1</option>
        <option value="0.2">0.2</option>
    </select>

    <label for="7">Subject #7 </label><input type="text" id="7" maxlength="5" value="">
    <select name="" id="op2">
        <option value="0.1">0.1</option>
        <option value="0.2">0.2</option>
    </select>

    <button onclick="result();">Calculate</button>
</form>
</div>
```

I'm spanish so I tried to calculate the academic results by following a method used here, don't loot at it. I'm focusing in I can not caltulate the result.

Comment: Are you sure you're putting javascript code at the end of the page (just before `</body>`)?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it, but the issue keeps on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines like this

```
var id1 = doc.getElementById("1").value;
```

only work if the element can be found in the document. This means that either the script needs to be loaded at the bottom of the page, or you have to move this code inside the `init` function that you call on `window.onload`.

Also, the variable `result` is local to the `init()` function, which means you cannot read it outside of it. So the value that is alerted is not assigned either. You can declare `result` outside of the functions, so both functions can read or set it.

So in short, you script could look like this:

```
var result; // Make global, so both functions can reach it.

function init() {
  // Var declaration is not needed if you add the `var` keyword later.
  // var id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6, id7, notabx, op1, op2, mu1, mu2;
  var doc = document;
  var id1 = doc.getElementById("1").value;
  var id2 = doc.getElementById("2").value;
  var id3 = doc.getElementById("3").value;
  var id4 = doc.getElementById("4").value;
  var id5 = doc.getElementById("5").value;
  var id6 = doc.getElementById("6").value;
  var id7 = doc.getElementById("7").value;
  var op1 = doc.getElementById("op").value;
  var op2 = doc.getElementById("op2").value;
  var bx = doc.getElementById("bx").value;
  // Shouldn't mu1 and mu2 get a value too?

  var FG = ( id1 + id2 + id3 + id4 + id5 ) / 5 ;
  var FE = ( id6 * mu1) + ( id7 * mu2 );

  // Remove the 'var' keyword below. You want to set the global, rather than 
  // declare a new local variable.
  result =  (bx * (60/100)) + (FG * (40/100)) + FE;
}

function showResult() {
  // Alert the global result variable.
  alert(result);
}

window.onload = init();
```

Alternatively, you could choose to do the calculation only when you click the button. Maybe that's even what you want. If you calculate it onload, the calculation will only be made with the values that are initially in the form. Any changes are not taken into account in the result.

As Anonymous mentioned in the comment, having a variable and a function both named result is asking for problems. So I renamed the function to `showResult`. You should change this in the HTML too, of course:

```
<button onclick="showResult();">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: The function also happens to be named result.

Comment: What a awesome answer, thank you. But I keep getting the undefined alert :/  I've made some modification but what is the issue now. (In the comment below are the modifications).

Comment: If I do the calculation when I click the button the result is NaN.